# Foundation modal vertical centering

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have an issue with Foundation Modal Reveal. By default when modal is open, modal has CSS set like this:

```
top: 100px;
```

How can I make it vertically centered? By that meaning that I have same amount of pixels above and below modal

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
top: 50%;
margin-top: -XXpx;
```

Where XX is half of modal block height